# Specifying cross-network (multiplex) terms in R's ERGM package

Tags: r, networking, social-networking, igraph

I have a research question which deals with a multiplex network, i.e. there are multiple edge-types which may (or may not) co-occur between two nodes. For example:

```
library(igraph)

relations <- data.frame(
             from    = c(1,1,2,3,4),
             to      = c(2,3,3,4,5),
             link    = c(1,1,1,0,0),
             funding = c(0,1,0,0,1),
             )
graph <- graph.data.frame(relations)
```

Note that two different types of relations exist, links and funding.

In my analysis, I am interested in triad-structures, especially transitive triads, i.e. if A -link-> B -link-> C then A -fund-> C. I have seen multiplex networks in the literature ([this great piece](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378873312000664)), which serves as an example, but also indicate R should be capable of doing this.

But, my problem is that I am unable to find any indication of the syntax for such triads across networks. I have seen the [PNet](http://sna.unimelb.edu.au/PNet) application to do this (TriangleABA from the manual), but I am unable to do this in R.  I am looking for something like

```
fit <- ergm( fundnet ~ edges + odegree + ttriple(funding) + ttripe(link) )
```

Instead of specifying types, I could also make the incidence matrices by using     `tcrossprod(funding,link)` for two-step via funding and than links.

Although I am not dead-set on R, my network may -depending on operationalization- be around 100.000 nodes with 300.000 edges. In R, I am confident I can scale this on a cluster of computers, hence my preference.

I would strongly appreciate any remarks or (hopefully) solutions!

Comment: Can you run `ergm` on a cluster? I mean, in parallel for a single large graph?

Comment: I believe so, as [this researcher](http://www.researchgate.net/post/Need_help_interpreting_ERGM_exponential_random_graph_model_result_for_large_network) seems to have done so. I've found examples in the following [documentation](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/rforge/xergm/man/btergm.html). 

So I'm not too worried about that. If worst comes to worst, I may be able to subset the network.

Comment: 1) The documentation you are referring to is from a different package called xergm, which is for longitudinal networks. 2) The ergm package does offer parallel support as well, but the parallel argument contains bugs in the current release version. 3) However, you should be able to use MPLE instead of MCMC on large networks, but there is no guarantee that the standard errors are not biased. 4) The article you are referencing deals with standard ERGMs ("multiplex" because multiple predictor relations are used). 5) There seems to be some confusion over terminology: multiplex != multilevel ERGM.

Comment: I see there are some issues concerning the clarity of my question & your answers.

1) xergm is indeed for longitudinal networks, which I am dealing with in my application. I neglected to mention this as the btergm and tergm function of this package accept ergm terms and my solution was expected to apply to any ergm.
2 ) I have noticed this is some instances (but not others)
3 ) Interesting, but if I understand correctly, btergm models use nonparametric bootstraps to reduce MPLE bias
4) I did not use the world multilevel, could you elaborate on the mixup you imply?

Comment: You are using the word "multiplex" for modeling several networks as "dependent variables" simultaneously, where these networks can influence each other and where they can have different baselines for things like reciprocity or triadic closure. This is usually called a "multilevel ERGM". See also here: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.socnet.2013.01.004. The Heaney paper you are mentioning is merely using multiple relations as "independent variables", and he calls this use of several relations a multiplex theory. Note also that multilevel networks are currently not supported by statnet and xergm.